# is null is concatenated at end in laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am printing Sql query below in Laravel

```
$CheckIfAssigned = Projects::select(DB::Raw('count(projects.id) as projects'))
                ->leftJoin('project_team as pt', 'projects.id', '=', 'pt.project_id')
                ->where(DB::Raw('(projects.id = '.$projectId.') AND ( project_manager_id = '.$LoggedInUserId.' OR pt.employee_id = '.$LoggedInUserId.')'))->toSql();
```

And the **Result** i am getting is :

```
select count(projects.id) as projects from `projects` left join
 `project_team` as `pt` on `projects`.`id` = `pt`.`project_id` 
where (projects.id = 13) AND ( project_manager_id = 9 OR pt.employee_id = 9) is null
```

Why there is `is null` in the Sql Query at the end even i did not write ?

Comment: I think you should use whereRaw instead where

Comment: @vijaykumar Thanks mate. . . .. It worked. ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `where` function is expecting a second parameter, and you didn't provide that, the default value of the second parameter is `null`, that's why the `is null` is appending to your query. You can use the `whereRaw` function instead to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel **where** requires three arguments. The first argument is the name of the column. The second argument is an operator, which can be any of the database's supported operators. Finally, the third argument is the value to evaluate against the column check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

```
Projects::select(DB::Raw('count(projects.id) as projects'))
                ->leftJoin('project_team as pt', 'projects.id', '=', 'pt.project_id')
                ->where(DB::Raw('(projects.id = '.$projectId.') AND ( project_manager_id = '.$LoggedInUserId.' OR pt.employee_id = '.$LoggedInUserId.')'))->toSql();
```

In your above code your not passing 2 OR 2nd and 3rd parameter That's why it was showing null. Instead you can try `whereRaw` Here whereRaw will accept query.

```
 Projects::select(DB::Raw('count(projects.id) as projects'))
                ->leftJoin('project_team as pt', 'projects.id', '=', 'pt.project_id')
                ->whereRaw('projects.id = ' .$projectId. ' AND ( project_manager_id = ' .$LoggedInUserId. ' OR pt.employee_id = ' . $LoggedInUserId)->toSql();
```